# $X^m=O_n$ implies $X^n=O_n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $X\in M_n(\mathbb C) $ and $m>n$ a positive integer. Does $X^m=O_n$ imply $X^n=O_n$?

My approach: I wrote the H-C theorem and started multiplying it by $m-n,m... $ until I get to something like $\alpha X^n=O_n$, but this doesn't imply $X^n=O_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.  One approach is as follows: if $X^m = 0$, then $X$ has only $0$ as its eigenvalue.  Thus, its characteristic polynomial is $p(x) = x^n$.  Now, apply the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Comment: @JustAnAmateur One can provide a proof involving kernels and induction only. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional space where $X$ acts, and consider the subspaces $\ker(X^p) = V_p$. These are increasing, that is, $V_p \subseteq V_{p+1}$. I claim that if $V_n\neq V$, then all the inclusions in the chain of $n$ proper subspaces
$0=V_0 \subseteq V_1\subseteq \cdots\subseteq V_n \subsetneq V$
are strict. This is a contradiction, since as soon as an inclusion is proper, the dimension goes up by one, meaning the dimension of $V$ is at least $n+1$. Indeed, suppose that for some $p<n$ we have $V_{p-1} =V_p$, and let us show that $V_p = V_{p+1}$. So suppose that $X^{p+1}v=0$. Then $Xv$ is in the kernel of $X^p$. Since we assumed this is the same as the kernel of $X^{p-1}$, we see that $X^pv=0$, and we're done.